# Spatially join points to polygons in ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, point, spatial-join, vector-grid

I am trying to join a point feature class to a gridded polygon feature class in arcGIS so that all the points are matched to the grid cell that they fall within. I would like to end up with an attributes table that contains the count of points that fall within each grid cell and the average, maximum and stdev value of all the points falling in each grid cell. I have multiple points falling within many of my grid cells.

I thought that this could be achieved by using the 'join' tool in the 'joins & relates' option or the 'spatial join' tool in the 'Analysis' toolbox in arcGIS. Unfortunately, these tools do not give me the output that I am looking for. When I use a point layer with 20024 points as the join_feature, the count column in the output joined feature class exceeds this value (20203). This count column should equal the number of rows in the original point layer.

I had wondered whether the tool was matching points to multiple grid cells if points spanned >1 cell, but apparently points do not have any width associated with them so this cannot be the problem. My grid was created using the 'create fishnet' tool and the boundaries of grid cells do not overlap.

Comment: "join the points to the grid cells that they fall within the most" -- I am not entirely sure I understand this part of your question, since a point feature doesn't have any width associated with it. Is it possible that some of your polygons are overlapping?

Comment: Hi Erica. Hmm, I had wondered whether arc did somehow associate a width with points (illogical I know) based on the mismatching counts, but if it doesn't then I am not sure what the problem is. The grid cells are not overlapping. I created the polygon grid with the 'create fishnet' tool. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: How many grids do you have? If 179, then perhaps it's including the polygons in the result list. If not... then I really don't know :)

Comment: 3600! I'm at a loss to know what the problem is. I think that I will have to resort to using R to do that calculations. THanks for your suggestions anyway.

Comment: In addition to the spatial join there are a couple of alternative ideas suggested [in this other Question](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/24843/how-can-i-aggregate-points-to-polygons) (which also mentions that Spatial Join is "a little buggy" when processing lots of features, which might be what's wrong in this case). Using the [Identity](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Identity/00080000000n000000/) tool might work as a different method.

Comment: If you are performing a One-to-Many join, then it is possible to have your results contain more features than the original.  Are you using your grid layer as the base and the points layer as the join layer?  If so, then the resulting layer will contain an extra count for every point that intersects the same polygon.  E.g., if you have one polygon with two points in it, there will be an extra count.  One polygon with four points - three extra counts, etc., etc.  It appears in your case, there were 179 cases of extra counts.

Comment: @ Baltok: I used 'join' in 'join & relates' menu when right clicking on the base polygon layer because of the problem you mention above with Spatial Join. The join feature should return the total count of points within the grid cell, regardless of how many. My output table has the correct number of rows in it (i.e 3600 which equals the number of grid cells in the base polygon layer), but the count is higher than it should be. The only thing that I can think that is happening is that arc is somehow assigning certain points to more than one cell?

Comment: @ Thanks Erica. I'll check them out but on first glance I don't think that they are going to give me the summaries that I want. Thanks for you help!

Comment: In that case, what results do you get when you join in reverse?  I.e., points are your target layer.  There are numerous other ways to play with your join to test how it is behaving.  You may also want to try the actual Spatial Join tool since it has some different options than the right click version.

Comment: If you use Identity, you can then pull the resulting table out into Excel and make a pivot table to summarize statistics.

Comment: @ Baltok: thanks. I have done this and everything looks as it should when done this way. I couldn't get the summary stats that I wanted in spatial join, but maybe I will look into it again in case I missed something. @ Erica: thanks for the other option.

Comment: I followed a link from @Erica's comment and found that there is a [Spatial Join fix in ArcGIS Desktop 10.0 SP5](http://downloads2.esri.com/support/downloads/other_/185410.0_SP5_Announcement.pdf) that may or may not address your issue.  In any event would you be able to edit your question to include details of the ArcGIS Desktop version and service pack that you are using, please?